# How to reference subnets from another virtual network/resource group when creating a NIC using ARM templates

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create a NIC for a VM in a resource group. The problem I have is that i'm trying to reference a subnet from another resource group in Azure. Therefore, I am having to reference it using subscription level deployments in ARM templates.

```
"subnetref": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('HUB Network RG'), '/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('HUB VNet'), '/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('HUB DC Subnet'))]"
```

Above is the subnet ref variable I am trying to create. I then have the below for the VM NIC i'm trying to create.

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
    "name": "[variables('nicnamedc1')]",
    "location": "[variables('location')]",
    "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
    "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
            {
                "name": "ipconfig1",
                "properties": {
                    "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                    "subnet": {
                        "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

I then get the below error.

> New-AzDeployment : 14:54:23 - Resource
>   Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces 'before-nic' failed with  message
>   '{   "error": {
>       "code": "InvalidRequestFormat",
>       "message": "Cannot parse the request.",
>       "details": [
>         {
>           "code": "InvalidJsonReferenceFormat",
>           "message": "Reference Id /subscriptions/404422c0-743d-4459-9db0-01892d0c7348/resourceGroups/hu
>   b-network-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/bsrgh-hub-vnetvirtualNetworks/subnetsdomain
>   is not formatted correctly. The Id is expected to reference resources
>   of type  virtualNetworks/subnets. Path
>   properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.subnet."

I think it is complaining about the format that I've done the subnetref variable at the top. Is there a better way of doing this or am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you forgot the `/` in your code:

```
"subnetref": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('HUB Network RG'), '/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('HUB VNet'), '/virtualNetworks/subnets/', parameters('HUB DC Subnet'))]"
```

but you are better of using `resourceId()` function:

```
resourceId(parameters('HUB Network RG'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('HUB VNet'), parameters('HUB DC Subnet'))
```

its a lot shorter and less error prone

Comment: your suggestion of resourceId() is a good one, but you omitted the subscription in there. For the complete reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourceid

Comment: From the question it isn't super clear but I think the vnet is in the same subscription just a different resource group.  You should omit the subscription if your template is deploying in the same subscription.

Comment: @DdW given the person is using `subscription().id` resourceId generated by my code is identical to his, but simpler.